# Vtiger Crm recording links broken

Tags: asterisk, vtiger

I have installed Vtiger 6.1 with FreePBX integrated on the same server. Everything is running as they should except the recording url.

When a call is completed the recording is saved properly but at the PBXManager i get links like this:

http://:8383/recording?id=4689476c3d214523b42bb329211af93a

It's clearly missing the server address but i can't find where it reads it from so that i can fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that integration is for SAME version of vtiger(including
   subversion)
2. Check that you did install like described in readme
   file.

Comment: I did all the steps as the quide is describing and even though it works perfectly the recording link generated fails. I can't find from where it reads the address to complete the url. I'm getting the feeling that there is an attribute needed that was left out of the quide and readme file for this.

Comment: Installation readme had some blind spots. I found out the missing spot and everything now works!